# set_select option in ajax+codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, html, codeigniter

how can i use a set_select option on ajax part for a dynamic dependent dropdown list, this list is clearing after validation errors, so i want to use set_select option here. kindly see below code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[name="relegion"]').on('change', function() {          
        var regID = $(this).val();
        if(regID) {
            document.write("ok");
            $.ajax({
                url: '/demo/main/selectcaste/'+regID,
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                success:function(data) {
                    $('select[name="caste"]').empty();
                    $('select[name="caste"]').append('<option value=1>'+ "Not Interested to specify" +'</option>');
                    $('select[name="caste"]').append('<option value=2>'+ "InterCaste" +'</option>');
                    $.each(data, function(key, value) { 

                        $('select[name="caste"]').append('<option value="'+ value.id +'">'+ value.name +'</option>');

                    });
                }
            });
        }else{
            $('select[name="caste"]').empty();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you show your controllers ?

Comment: Could you please give us more clarification on your requirement .? Question not clear

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need something like this,

View code.

```
<select name="category" id="category">
    <option>Pilih Kategori Kelas</option>
    <option value="1">category 1</option>
    <option value="2">category 2</option>
</select>

<select name="sub_category" id="sub_category">
    <option>Pilih category Kelas</option>
</select>
```

AJAX code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#category').on('change',function(){
      var category_id = $(this).val();
      if(category_id){
           $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'<?php echo base_url()."profile_kelas/get_sub_category";?>',
                data: {
                     category_id : category_id
                },
                success:function(html){
                     $('#sub_category').html(html);
               }
          });

      }else{
           $('#sub_category').html('<option>Pilih Sub category Kelas</option>');
      }
 });
});
```

My Controller code.

```
public function get_sub_category(){
    $data = $this->model_profile->get_sub_category($_POST['category_id']);
    foreach ($data as $row) {
        echo '<option value="'.$row->id.'">'.$row->sub_category.'</option>';
    }
}
```

You can make your parent category dynamically.

Comment: No it's not working at all. After the form has been submitted, clears all value. This approach is also not working. $output .= '<option value="' . $row->id . '"' . set_select("block_id", $row->id) . '>' . $row->block_name . '</option>';